# Google Authentication in Server-Side Blazor not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, google-authentication

I'm trying to add Google Authentication on my Blazor server app, and can't get it to work on my localhost. When I click the Login button, it brings me to the Google account chooser, where I pick an account to use for logging in. After I pick an account, it goes back to my localhost Login page where the OnGetCallbackAsync shows that GoogleUser.IsAuthenticated is false.

Below is the Startup.cs

```
namespace RecruitmentApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
                //options.UseSqlite("DataSource=app.db"));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:image", "picture");
            });

            // From: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1554
            // Adds HttpContextAccessor
            // Used to determine if a user is logged in
            // and what their username is
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
            // Required for HttpClient support in the Blazor Client project
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
            // Pass settings to other components
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();



            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code inside Login.cshtml.cs where the problem is showing.

```
namespace RecruitmentApp.Pages
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            string provider = "Google";
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Page("./Login",
                pageHandler: "Callback",
                values: new { returnUrl }),
            };

            return new ChallengeResult(provider, authenticationProperties);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var GoogleUser = this.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();

            // -----> !!! PROBLEM GoogleUser.IsAuthenticated is returning false!!!!

            if (GoogleUser.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    RedirectUri = this.Request.Host.Value
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(GoogleUser), authProperties);
            }

            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

In console.developers.google.com, an OAuth 2.0 Client ID has been set-up with the type "Web application", with ClientID and Secret added to the secrets.json file of the project.

The OAuth Client ID has been edited with the following authorized Redirect URIs:

https://localhost:44319/Login
https://localhost:44319/signin-google

I can't see what's wrong why it's returning GoogleUser.IsAuthenticated = false after choosing the google user. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a working example here: https://www.blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/19

Comment: @MichaelWashington: No it is not working failing with ```fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at ...```

Comment: It is funny and not at all trivial how and why modification of `UseCookiePolicy()` strategy is the key, yet it works!)

Comment: I would suggest you to upgrade your nuget packages to the latest. Plus, if it still fails you can use the JavaScript SDK for authenticating users.